# MySQL procedure cases won't return null

Tags: mysql, null, procedure, case-statement

I am writing a procedure that will show whether a current student is in a table. After testing it, I am getting a couple of errors...

```
Create procedure stuID(p_id int)    
begin   
    declare v_msg varchar(100);
    declare count_id int;

    select count(*) into count_id from students where id = p_id; 


    If null then
        set v_msg := 'null';
    Elseif count_cl_id = 1 then
        set v_msg := 1;
    Elseif count_cl_id = 0 then
        set v_msg := 0;
    End if;

    Select v_msg;
end;
```

So then I created another procedure to test these...

Create procedure test_stuID ()
    begin

```
    -- Test with null
    call stuID(null);

    -- Test with invalid ID
    call stuID('0');

    -- Test with String
    call stuID( 'false' );

    -- Test with true ID
    call stuID('25');

end;
```

#

Two problems:

1) the null case doesn't return v_msg as 'null'

2) the real valid ID 25 doesn't get returned.

What am I doing wrong??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

2 errors:

1) `If null` should be replaced with `if count_id is null`

and

2) you are using `count_cl_id` to compare whereas `count_id` is the param name.

I tested on my system with the corrections and is working fine.

Comment: hm. I saw this and tried it (since it makes sense). but it didn't work. I then typed: call stuID(null);
And got the v_msg as 0, not null. Thoughts?

Comment: I edited my answer check it please and let me know if it helps

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, did you get a null as the output? or 0? I keep getting 0 as the result when I asked the v_msg to be set to 'null' for the null case. Thanks

Comment: you are returning a int type variable and trying to set a string value in it , does that makes sense ?

Comment: I thought v_msg was declared as a varchar. So it should return as a string?